# cakephp check the num after delete

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I want to check the num of market if true num then delete and redirect in index else redirect error

in controller:

```
public function admin_verif_num() {

        $this->set('title_for_layout', __('verification'));
        $this->Market->recursive = 2;

        $markets = $this->Market->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('Market.num_mark')
        ));
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $num= $this->request->data['Market']['num_mark'];
        foreach ($markets as $nums) {
            if ($nums == $num) {
                $id= $this->request->id;
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('good'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));

         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'delete',$id,true), null, __('Are you sure?'));
             } else{
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('error'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
          $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_verif_delete_num'));

             }   
        }
       }       
      $this->set('markets', $markets);
   }
```

in view:

```
<?php
                echo $this->Form->label('num_mark', '  : طلب الع'); ?>

                 <?php echo $this->Form->input('num_mark',array('label' => false )); 

                 ?>
```

the result is `http://localhost/bib/admin/markets/delete/1`
but not delete what is the true code ?

Comment: what is the problem please ? thank you for help me :)

Comment: Please don't act like a child that is denied its sweets, people don't sit here 24/7 to answer everybody's questions in time. Also it's not clear what you are asking for, in case your `delete()` action isn't working, then you should at least show the corresponding code (and it wouldn't hurt if it were indented it properly).

Comment: sorry @ndm in action delete  ` public function admin_delete($id = null) {

  if (!$id) {

   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for market'), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));

   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_index'));

  }

  if ($this->Market->delete($id, true)) {

   $this->Session->setFlash(__('the market deleted'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));

   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_index'));

  }`

Comment: sorry for bad explication.  I have a maket how's have id, num_mark,...  I want when delete market I check the num if is a correct num then delete .